# Is Reflection needed to apply the correct generic adapter to my object dynamically

Tags: java, generics, reflection, polymorphism, xmladapter

I am currently working on a serialization routine which uses a library of generically typed adapters.  If the object being serialized is an instance of one of the specific adapters I have, then I need to call that adapter on the object prior to performing my other serialization procedures.

The following code works:

```
private final static String serialize(Object obj, Map<Class<?>, 
        XmlAdapter<?,?>> classToAdapterMap) throws JAXBException 
{
    Object adaptedObj = null;

    for (Class<?> clazz : classToAdapterMap.keySet()) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) {
            XmlAdapter<?,?> adapter = classToAdapterMap.get(clazz);
            Class<?>[] argTypes = new Class[] {clazz};
            try {
                Method method = adapter.getClass().getMethod("marshal", argTypes);
                adaptedObj = method.invoke(adapter, obj);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle method retrieval and invocation related exceptions
            }
        }
    }

    // serialize
}
```

However, I had originally thought that I would be able to do this more simply, for example with code like:

```
/* DOES NOT WORK */
private final static String serialize(Object obj, Map<Class<?>, 
        XmlAdapter<?,?>> classToAdapterMap) throws JAXBException 
{
    Object adaptedObj = null;

    for (Class<?> clazz : classToAdapterMap.keySet()) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) {
            XmlAdapter<?,?> adapter = classToAdapterMap.get(clazz);
            adaptedObj = adapter.marshal(clazz.cast(obj));
            break;
        }
    }

    // serialize
}
```

Clearly the problem is that the wildcard generically typed adapter isn't guaranteed to handle an object of type `clazz`.  However, I can't indicate that these two are the same by changing the method signature—as I might otherwise do—to `private final static <T> String serialize(Object obj, Map<Class<T>,  XmlAdapter<?,T>> classToAdapterMap)`, because the map needs to hold adapters of all different types.

What would be a better way to do this?  Or should I stick with the Reflection based solution?

Thanks in advance,

-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions to circumvent this problem.

Most likely, the easiest one is **using raw types**: don't specify the type parameters for the `adapter`, and the compiler will *happily* accept the `marshall` call (with a raw type warning of course):

```
XmlAdapter adapter = classToAdapterMap.get(clazz);
adaptedObj = adapter.marshal(obj);
```

(This is actually roughly the same solution as Bastian's, without the intermediate type)

If you don't like raw types, you may choose the **unchecked cast** to an `Object`-parameterized adapter. It's not really better, but it also works (by tricking the compiler…):

```
XmlAdapter<?, Object> adapter = (XmlAdapter<?, Object>) classToAdapterMap.get(clazz);
adaptedObj = adapter.marshal(obj);
```

My last solution is to use a *type parameter at the method level*. This time, what you do is semantically correct (as long as the map itself is correct), and the unchecked cast really means “*I know what I am doing here*”:

```
private final static <T> String serialize(T obj, Map<Class<?>, 
        XmlAdapter<?,?>> classToAdapterMap) throws JAXBException 
{
    Object adaptedObj = null;

    for (Class<?> clazz : classToAdapterMap.keySet()) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) {
            try {
                XmlAdapter<?, ? super T> adapter = (XmlAdapter<?, ? super T>) classToAdapterMap.get(clazz);
                adaptedObj = adapter.marshal(obj);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // serialize
}
```

The semantic correctness comes from the following:

- you may consider `T` to be the actual class of `obj` since `T` is a method-bound parameter, not used elsewhere in the signature;
- `clazz` is a super type of the type of `T` since we checked `clazz.isInstance(obj)`;
- `adapter` can handle instances of `clazz` or a super-type of it since it is how the map was built;
- by consequent, `adapter` can handle all instances of an (unknown) super type of `T`, hence the `? super T` declaration.

Comment: Thanks Didier.  This is a great summary of available options.  I ended up going with your third solution—adding a type parameter to the serialization method—combined with Bastian's suggestion of subclassing XmlAdapter.  (I realized shortly after posting this question that I am getting no benefit out of using a map here, because the _bound type_ of the desired adapter may be a super-class, rather than a match, to the type of the object being serialized.  Thus a list of adapters capable of reporting their type seems cleaner to me.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler and safer way without using reflection:

At first, we need a small specialization of the `XmlAdapter` as it allows us to ask the adapter for the type it can handle.

```
public abstract class TalkingXmlAdapter<ValueType, BoundType> extends XmlAdapter<ValueType, BoundType> {

    public abstract Class<BoundType> getBoundType();

}
```

My custom adapters now need to extend `TalkingXmlAdapter`:

```
public class AppleXmlAdapter extends TalkingXmlAdapter<String, Apple> {

    @Override
    public Class<Apple> getBoundType() {
        return Apple.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Apple unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Unmarshalling Apple");
        return new Apple();
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Apple v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Marshalling Apple");
        return "Apple";
    }

}


public class BananaXmlAdapter extends TalkingXmlAdapter<String, Banana> {

    @Override
    public Class<Banana> getBoundType() {
        return Banana.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Banana unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Unmarshalling Banana");
        return new Banana();
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Banana v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Marshalling Banana");
        return "Banana";
    }

}
```

That allows us to write a simplified serialization method:

```
public class SimpleSerializer {

    public static final String serialize(Object obj, List<TalkingXmlAdapter> allAdapters) throws Exception {
        Object adaptedObj = null;

        for (TalkingXmlAdapter adapter : allAdapters) {
            if (adapter.getBoundType().isInstance(obj)) {
                adaptedObj = adapter.marshal(obj);
                break;
            }
        }
        // serialize
        System.out.println("Simple serializing for " + obj.toString());
        return "Simply serialized " + obj.toString();
    }

}
```

Using the code e.g. like in the subsequent listing shows the behavior you want:

```
    List<TalkingXmlAdapter> allAdapters = new ArrayList<>();
    allAdapters.add(new AppleXmlAdapter());
    allAdapters.add(new BananaXmlAdapter());

    SimpleSerializer.serialize(new Banana(), allAdapters);
    SimpleSerializer.serialize("Lemmon", allAdapters);
    SimpleSerializer.serialize(new Apple(), allAdapters);
```

Output:

```
Marshalling Banana
Simple serializing for generic.adapter.Banana@659e0bfd
Simple serializing for Lemmon
Marshalling Apple
Simple serializing for generic.adapter.Apple@2a139a55
```

To sum this up, the solution gives you following advantages:

- You don't need reflection which simplifies your code.
- You need fewer generic programming in your serialization routine which simplifies your code.
- The solution is more safe. Note that no type cast is needed. Every adapter accepts the type `Object`. However by using the generic method `getBoundType()` you can ensure the specific runtime type is the correct one. When building your map as in the reflection solution, a wrongly mapped class results in a runtime exception. In the proposed solution the super class `TalkingXmlAdapter` enforces each adapter to state their correct type by using generics.

The price you pay is:

- Introduction of a new super type.
- Requires small adaptions for your custom adapters.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Bastian.  The idea of using a list of subclassed XmlAdapters which add methods to report there bound and value types was actually an approach I settled on after making this post.  As Didier mentions, the way around reflection here is by using raw types (which I did not consider at all).

Comment: I would like to mention though, that there is a very important difference between `adapter.getBoundType().equals(obj.getClass())` and what I'm sure you meant which would be `adapter.getBoundType().isInstance(obj)`.  The latter allows me to use adapters typed to handle super-classes of my actual objects being serialized.  This is very important to my actual use case.  It does bring up the possible issue (which I glossed over in my post) that the behavior is undefined if multiple adapters handle different super-classes, but I avoid this through choice of adapters.

Comment: You're right Dan, using `isInstance(obj)` improves flexibility. I adapted my solution. Thanks for the remark.